# Trigger notification in front-end after a Rake task completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a small Rails app to help search OIDs used by an SNMP Simulator.
These are all loaded into Redis and I have a Rake task that does an `snmptranslate` for each so that we have a nice meaningful translation of that OID.
I have a search field that triggers an AJAX search and allows you to search by string representation.
The Rake task is quite long (easily 3-4 minutes), how could I alert the user that it completes and that he can now lookup OIDs by string representation?
Would **Action Cable** be suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the ideal solution but ActionCable should definitely do the job. Especially as you are already using Redis.

[Here somebody solved a similar problem with its use.](https://medium.com/@tdaniel/using-actioncable-to-provide-updates-on-background-job-in-your-rails-app-29b6fd41ed70)

Comment: Thanks, really helpful article!